# FATAL EXCEPTION: highpool[11] when send and receive payload using nearby connections API

Tags: google-nearby

I have an application android that using nearby connections API to communicate between 2 devices. But when i run in long time it throw an exception and restart service.

```
DeviceDoctorHandler    Crash Hash: ad2abb125bf96bd465c5dbafb8140da7ddfbfd31
DeviceDoctorHandler    Shushing crash.
DeviceDoctorHandler    FATAL EXCEPTION: highpool[11]
DeviceDoctorHandler    Process: com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection, PID: 31625
DeviceDoctorHandler    java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
DeviceDoctorHandler     at pj.a(:com.google.android.gms@11746430:24)
DeviceDoctorHandler     at pj.a(:com.google.android.gms@11746430:14)
DeviceDoctorHandler     at pj.put(:com.google.android.gms@11746430:3)
DeviceDoctorHandler     at xvs.a(:com.google.android.gms@11746430:139)
DeviceDoctorHandler     at xus.a(:com.google.android.gms@11746430:16)
DeviceDoctorHandler     at xup.run(:com.google.android.gms@11746430:8)
DeviceDoctorHandler     at mmu.run(:com.google.android.gms@11746430:26)
DeviceDoctorHandler     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
DeviceDoctorHandler     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
DeviceDoctorHandler     at mse.run(:com.google.android.gms@11746430)
DeviceDoctorHandler     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
DeviceDoctorHandler
```

Can anyone help me

Many thanks!